# How to read spring boot tomcat properties another user defined bean before initialization?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to read spring boot ssl keystore password value from user defined spring bean and set to SSL property server.ssl.key-password.

```
@Component
public class KeyStorePasswordBean {
    public String password() {
        //implementation
    }    
}
```

I tried with EnvironmentPostProcessor but NullPointer exception thrown because KeyStorePasswordBean bean will be initialized after EnvironmentPostProcessor

```
public class PropertyEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    @Autowired
    KeyStorePasswordBean keyStorePasswordBean;

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        String keystorePassword = keyStorePasswordBean.password(); //NullPointerException
        System.out.println("password: " + keystorePassword);
    }
}
```

How to handle this in spring boot?
Thinking on how to load KeyStorePasswordBean bean to spring context before tomcat server initialization start.

I am using spring boot version 2.25 and spring version 5.2.4

Answer (score 1):

you can read the following property via:

```
ConfigurableEnvironment environment
```

like that:

```
environment.getProperty("NAME_OF_YOUR_PROPERTIES")
```

then you can create and add your custom property source to the environment (with 'server.ssl.key-password' property)

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("server.ssl.key-password", property); // property = environment.getProperty("NAME_OF_YOUR_PROPERTIES")
environment.getPropertySources().addLast(new MapPropertySource("muCustomPropertySource", properties));
```

also, read the following article - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-environmentpostprocessor